# Can PowerBI load and display product images?

Tags: powerbi

I was reading https://visualbi.com/blogs/microsoft/powerbi/dynamically-display-images-power-bi/ on how to load images in PBI.

Does it mean that I can provide the images url link and powerbi is able to render them onto the dashboard?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can display images on your dashboard by setting up your data model and linking it with the Image URLs. You can create a public folder on one drive or any other platform and use the URL to create your data model. Just remember that the URLs should be accessible by public (all).

 
Some visuals where you can use images are Slicers, Dynamic Filters, Image Viewers, Tables, Matrix, KPI charts etc.

 
Check this blog to learn more: "https://blog.gbrueckl.at/2018/01/storing-images-powerbi-analysis-services-data-models/"